# GeoQuery MongoDB from SpringBoot MongoRepository

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, mongorepository

I am trying to perform a complex GeoQuery from Spring Boot MongoRepository using @Query annotation.
Following is my Document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e96c08322f74b00078cfff1"),
    "category" : "Services",
    "businessType" : "MyCommunityStore",
    "businessId" : "sin5e96c08322f74b00078cfff1",
    "promoted" : true,
    "banner" : true,
    "signed" : true,
    "geoLocation" : [ 
        -117.1264293, 
        32.9641416
    ]
}
```

I need my Query to do following tasks:

1. Filter all the documents with **promoted** flag **"true"**.
2. Sort these documents on the basis of distance from given point [x,y]

Can anyone help me with writing this query?

Following Query is giving Error:

```
{ 'promoted':true, 'geoLocation' : { '$near' : [-117.1264293, 32.9641416], '$maxDistance' : 30.00}})
```

Error logtrace:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Point must not be null!
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.NearQuery.(NearQuery.java:193) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.NearQuery.near(NearQuery.java:254) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.NearQuery.near(NearQuery.java:237) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryExecution$GeoNearExecution.doExecuteQuery(MongoQueryExecution.java:157) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryExecution$GeoNearExecution.execute(MongoQueryExecution.java:149) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.doExecute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:126) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:101) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:618) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.searchGeoLocationNear(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.searchGeoLocationNear(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.linkscreens.mycommunity.service.BusinessServiceImpl.getBannerDocuments(BusinessServiceImpl.java:261) ~[classes/:na]
at com.linkscreens.mycommunity.controller.BusinessController.getBannerDocuments(BusinessController.java:77) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_265]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_265]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_265]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return type of my Repository Method was GeoResults and it did not have a Point type method argument.
Changing return type to List worked.